# restoring full farm backup does not show sites

Tags: 2010, backup, restore

I have backed up my sharepoint trial server and uninstall it. then reinstalled it from scratch and restored from the backup.

however, when I try to go to sites, or subsites, I get

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2012 18:52:41 GMT
Connection: close`

if I try to explicitly define the path, like, server:81/default.aspx,

I get file not found error.

Is there anything else that I need to do after restore?

Comment: Did you do a SharePoint farm backup, or a content database SQL backup?

Comment: @Russel, I did farm backup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a web application first that listens on server:81 and then replace the Content DB for that new web app with the one you restored

Comment: So I need to do fresh install, then create the web application listening 81, then do the restore? is that right?

Comment: Correct, your database only contains the SharePoint content itself.  It doesn't know anything about the settings IIS needs.  You might also have to configure your Alternate Access Mappings as well

Comment: no, it does not seem to be working.. Still 404 NOT FOUND error.

Comment: I reinstalled the server, created a web application listening 82, then performed restore. but I am not able to see the previous sites in server:81/

Comment: I think it does not restore the system properly, there are many errors in the log which I will as another question